# Gazebo error: Robot not moving although apply_joint_effort applied

Tags: gazebo, ros2, rviz, rclpy

This is my state publisher node executable

```
from geometry_msgs.msg import TransformStamped
import tf2_ros
import tf2_geometry_msgs  # This import is necessary for using transform_datatypes
import math
import numpy as np
from rclpy.node import Node
from sensor_msgs.msg import JointState
from intro_robot.robot_controller import RobotController
from urdf_parser_py.urdf import URDF

class FramePublisher():

    def __init__(self):
        self.node = rclpy.create_node('giraff_robot')
        self.tf_broadcaster = tf2_ros.StaticTransformBroadcaster(self.node)
        self.publish_rate = 10
        self.rate = self.node.create_rate(self.publish_rate)
        self.joint_state_publisher = self.node.create_publisher(JointState, '/joint_states', 10)
        self.node.declare_parameter('robot_description', '')
        if self.node.has_parameter('robot_description'):
            self.robot_description = self.node.get_parameter('robot_description').get_parameter_value().string_value
        else:
            self.node.get_logger().error("Parameter 'robot_description' is missing!")
        self.node.create_subscription(
            JointState,
            'joint_states',
            self.joint_state_callback,
            10  # QoS profile depth
        )

    def joint_state_callback(self, updated_msg, joint_name=None, position=None):
        # Process joint state message
        joint_state_msg = JointState()
        if updated_msg:
            print("Received Joint State:")
            print("Header: ", updated_msg.header)
            print("Joint Names: ", updated_msg.name)
            print("Joint Positions: ", updated_msg.position)            
            joint_state_msg.header = updated_msg.header
            joint_state_msg.name = [updated_msg.name]  # Add your joint names
            print('giraff')
            print(updated_msg.position)
            position = float(updated_msg.position[0])
            print(updated_msg.position)
            joint_state_msg.position = [position] # Add your joint positions
        else:
            print("Received Joint State:")
            print("Header: ", self.get_clock().now().to_msg())
            print("Joint Names: ", joint_name)
            print("Joint Positions: ", position) 
            joint_state_msg.header.stamp = self.get_clock().now().to_msg()
            joint_state_msg.name = [joint_name]  # Add your joint names
            position = float(position)
            joint_state_msg.position = [position]  # Add your joint positions

        # Publish joint state information
        self.joint_state_publisher.publish(joint_state_msg)
        
        self.update_tf(joint_state_msg.position, joint_state_msg.name)

    def quaternion_from_euler(self, ai, aj, ak):
        ai /= 2.0
        aj /= 2.0
        ak /= 2.0
        ci = math.cos(ai)
        si = math.sin(ai)
        cj = math.cos(aj)
        sj = math.sin(aj)
        ck = math.cos(ak)
        sk = math.sin(ak)
        cc = ci*ck
        cs = ci*sk
        sc = si*ck
        ss = si*sk


        q = np.empty((4, ))
        q[0] = cj*sc - sj*cs
        q[1] = cj*ss + sj*cc
        q[2] = cj*cs - sj*sc
        q[3] = cj*cc + sj*ss

        return q
    



    def update_tf(self, position, joint_name):
        J = RobotController.compute_forward_kinematics_from_configuration(position)

        x = J[1,:3]
        y = J[2,:3]
        z = J[3,:3]
        # Extract the rotational part of the Jacobian
        rotational_jacobian = J[3:, :]
        joint_velocities = np.gradient(position, dt=0.01, axis=0, edge_order=2)
        # Calculate the angular velocities (roll, pitch, yaw rates)
        orientation_rates = np.dot(rotational_jacobian, joint_velocities)
        roll = orientation_rates[0]
        pitch = orientation_rates[1]
        yaw = orientation_rates[2]
        # Parse the URDF
        try:
            with open(self.robot_description, 'r') as urdf_file:
                self.robot_desc = URDF.from_xml_string(urdf_file.read())
        except Exception as e:
            self.get_logger().error(f"Error parsing URDF: {e}")
            self.robot_desc = None
        for joint in self.robot_desc.joints:
            if joint.name == joint_name:
                frame = joint.child
                parent_frame = joint.parent
                return joint.parent, joint.child
        self.publish_tf(x, y, z, roll, pitch, yaw, frame, parent_frame)


    def publish_tf(self, x, y, z, roll, pitch, yaw, frame, parent_frame):
        t = TransformStamped()
        t.header.stamp = self.node.get_clock().now().to_msg()
        t.header.frame_id = parent_frame
        t.child_frame_id = frame
        t.transform.translation.x = x
        t.transform.translation.y = y
        t.transform.translation.z = z

        q = self.quaternion_from_euler(roll, pitch, yaw)
        t.transform.rotation.x = q[0]
        t.transform.rotation.y = q[1]
        t.transform.rotation.z = q[2]
        t.transform.rotation.w = q[3]

        # Publish the transforms
        try:
             self.tf_broadcaster.sendTransform(t)
             print("Successfully published transform.")
             print(f"Transform lookup time: {t.header.stamp}")
             print(f"{t.child_frame_id}")
             print(f"{t.header.frame_id}")
        except Exception as e:
             print(f"Failed to publish transform {e}.")
             print(f"Transform lookup time: {t.header.stamp}")
        self.rate.sleep()

def main():
    rclpy.init()
    robot = FramePublisher()

    timer_period = 1.0 #upload this file to vm
    try:
        while rclpy.ok():
            timer1 = robot.node.create_timer(1.0, lambda:robot.publish_tf(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 'leg_link', 'base_link'))
            timer2 = robot.node.create_timer(1.1, lambda:robot.publish_tf(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 'arm_link', 'leg_link'))
            timer3 = robot.node.create_timer(1.1, lambda:robot.publish_tf(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 'end_effector', 'arm_link'))
            timer4 = robot.node.create_timer(1.1, lambda:robot.publish_tf(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, np.radians(30.0), 0.0, 'tool_mic', 'end_effector'))
            rclpy.spin(robot.node)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        timer1.cancel()
        timer2.cancel()
        timer3.cancel()
        timer4.cancel()
        robot.node.destroy_node()
        rclpy.shutdown()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is my robot controller node:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rclpy
from rclpy.node import Node
from control_msgs.msg import JointTrajectoryControllerState
from trajectory_msgs.msg import JointTrajectory, JointTrajectoryPoint
from gazebo_msgs.srv import ApplyJointEffort
from sensor_msgs.msg import JointState
import tf2_ros
from urdf_parser_py.urdf import URDF
from builtin_interfaces.msg import Time, Duration


class RobotController(Node):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__('robot_controller')
        buffer_size = 10.0
        self.tf_buffer = tf2_ros.Buffer(cache_time=tf2_ros.Duration(seconds=10.0, nanoseconds=10.0))
        self.tf_listener = tf2_ros.TransformListener(self.tf_buffer, self)
        self.joint_trajectory_publisher = self.create_publisher(JointTrajectory, '/joint_trajectory', 10)
        self.joint_state_publisher = self.create_publisher(JointState, '/joint_states', 10)
        self.joint_effort_srv_client= self.create_client(ApplyJointEffort, '/apply_joint_effort')
        self.declare_parameter('robot_description', '')
        if self.has_parameter('robot_description'):
            self.robot_description = self.get_parameter('robot_description').get_parameter_value().string_value
        else:
            self.get_logger().error("Parameter 'robot_description' is missing!")
        # Parse the URDF
        try:
            with open(self.robot_description, 'r') as urdf_file:
                self.robot_desc = URDF.from_xml_string(urdf_file.read())
        except Exception as e:
            self.get_logger().error(f"Error parsing URDF: {e}")
            self.robot_desc = None
            # Wait for the service to be available
        while not self.joint_effort_srv_client.wait_for_service(timeout_sec=5.0):
            self.get_logger().info('Service not available, waiting...')


    '''def listen_tf(self):
        try:
            transform1 = self.tf_buffer.lookup_transform('base_link', 'leg_link', rclpy.time.Time())
            transform2 = self.tf_buffer.lookup_transform('leg_link', 'arm_link', rclpy.time.Time())
            transform3 = self.tf_buffer.lookup_transform('arm_link', 'end_effector', rclpy.time.Time())
            transform4 = self.tf_buffer.lookup_transform('end_effector', 'tool_mic', rclpy.time.Time())
            self.get_logger().info(f'Transform received from base link to leg link: {transform1}')
            self.get_logger().info(f'Transform received from leg link to arm link: {transform2}')
            self.get_logger().info(f'Transform received from arm link to end effector: {transform3}')
            self.get_logger().info(f'Transform received from end effector to microphone tool: {transform4}')
        except (tf2_ros.LookupException, tf2_ros.ConnectivityException, tf2_ros.ExtrapolationException) as e:
            self.get_logger().warn(f'Failed to lookup transform: {e}')'''

    def get_cost(self, config1, config2):
        return np.linalg.norm(np.array(config1) - np.array(config2)).astype(int)

    def nearest(self, graph, new_node):
        nearest = None
        min_distance = 100

        for node in graph:
            distance = self.get_cost(new_node, node)
            
            if (distance <= min_distance) and distance!=0:
                min_distance = distance
                nearest = node
        
        return nearest


    def extend(self, q_nearest, q_random, step_size=10):
        new_node = np.zeros(4)

        # Extend from the nearest node towards the sampled point
        delta_x1 = q_random[0] - q_nearest[0]
        delta_x2 = q_random[1] - q_nearest[1]
        delta_x3 = q_random[2] - q_nearest[2]
        delta_x4 = q_random[3] - q_nearest[3]
        norm = np.linalg.norm(np.array([delta_x1, delta_x2, delta_x3, delta_x4]))
    
        delta_x1 /= norm
        delta_x2 /= norm
        delta_x3 /= norm
        delta_x4 /= norm
        
        if norm>step_size:            
            new_node[0] = (q_nearest[0] + (step_size * delta_x1)).astype(int)
            new_node[1] = (q_nearest[1] + (step_size * delta_x2)).astype(int)
            new_node[2] = (q_nearest[2] + (step_size * delta_x3)).astype(int)
            new_node[3] = (q_nearest[3] + (step_size * delta_x4)).astype(int)    
        else:
            new_node = q_random
        
        
        return new_node


    def rewire(self, near_nodes, idx, q_new):
        near_nodes[idx] = q_new
        

    def is_clear(self, node, obstacles):
        # Check if the path from 'start' to 'end' is clear
        # The obstacles parameter is a list of Node objects representing obstacle positions

        # Simple collision detection for illustration purposes
        for obs in obstacles:
            if (self.get_cost(node, obs)<=0) :
                return False  # Collision detected

        return True  # Path is clear

    def get_trajectory(self, q_goal, q_init):
        graph = [q_init]
        
            
        while self.get_cost(q_goal, q_init)>0:
            q_random = [np.random.randint(q_goal[0]-1, q_goal[0]+1), np.random.randint(q_goal[1]-1, q_goal[1]+1), np.random.randint(q_goal[2]-1, q_goal[2]+1), np.random.randint(q_goal[3]-1, q_goal[3]+1)]
            if self.is_clear(q_random, graph):
                q_nearest = self.nearest(graph, q_random) 
                q_new = self.extend(q_nearest, q_random)
                min_cost = self.get_cost(q_goal,q_nearest)
        
                near_nodes = [node for node in graph if (self.get_cost(q_new, node) <= min_cost)] 
                for idx, near_node in enumerate(near_nodes):
                    if self.is_clear(near_node, graph) and np.all(np.array(graph))!=0:                   
                        if (self.get_cost(q_goal, near_node) + self.get_cost(q_new, near_node)) < min_cost:
                            min_cost = self.get_cost(q_goal, near_node) + self.get_cost(q_new, near_node)
                if (self.is_joint_okay(q_new)) and (not self.is_singular(self.compute_forward_kinematics_from_configuration(q_new))):
                    graph.append(q_new)
                else:
                    q_new += np.array([0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1])
                    graph.append(q_new)
                for idx, near_node in enumerate(near_nodes):
                    if self.is_clear(near_node, graph) and np.all(np.array(graph))!=0: 
                        if (self.get_cost(q_goal, q_new) + self.get_cost(q_new, near_node))<self.get_cost(q_goal, near_node):
                            self.rewire(near_nodes, idx, q_new)  

                
                    q_init = q_new    
        return graph



    def compute_inertia_matrix(self):
        num_links = len(self.robot_desc.link_map) - 2 
        M = np.zeros((num_links, 4, 4))
        for idx, (link_name,link) in enumerate(self.robot_desc.link_map.items()):
            if link_name!='world' or link_name!='tool_mic':
                inertial = link.inertial
                if inertial is not None and inertial.inertia is not None:
                    if idx>3:
                        break
                    M[idx-1]  = np.array([[inertial.inertia.ixx, -inertial.inertia.ixy, -inertial.inertia.ixz, 0],
                        [-inertial.inertia.ixy, inertial.inertia.iyy, -inertial.inertia.iyz, 0],
                        [-inertial.inertia.ixz, -inertial.inertia.iyz, inertial.inertia.izz, 0],
                        [0, 0, 0, 0]])

        return M
            

    def compute_coriolis_matrix(self, M, q, qd):
        n = len(q)
        C = np.zeros((n, n))
        q_alt_symbols = {f'q{k}': sp.symbols(f'q{k}') for k in range(n)}
        qd_alt_symbols = {f'qd{k}': sp.symbols(f'qd{k}') for k in range(n)}
        for k in range(n):
            for i in range(n):
                for j in range(n):
                    if q[k] != 0.0 or qd[k] != 0.0:
                        q_alt = q_alt_symbols[f'q{k}']
                        qd_alt = qd_alt_symbols[f'qd{k}']
 
                        C[i, j] += 0.5 * (sp.diff(M[k][i, j], q_alt) - sp.diff(M[k][j, i], q_alt)) * qd_alt
                    else:
                        # Handle the case where the joint position is zero
                        # For example, set the derivative to zero or handle it based on your system's dynamics
                        C[i, j] += 0.0  # Set derivative to zero

        return C


    def compute_forward_kinematics_from_configuration(self, q):

        T01, T12, T23, T34, T4ee = self.compute_transform_matrix(q)
        T_total = T01 @ T12 @ T23 @ T34 @ T4ee
        
        return  np.array([T_total[0, 3], T_total[1, 3], T_total[2, 3]])
    

    
    def compute_transform_matrix(self, q, theta5 = 30):
        # Extract joint angles and prismatic displacements
        theta1, theta2, d3, theta4 = q
        

        # Define robot parameters (replace these with the actual parameters of your robot)
        L1 = 0.1
        L2 = 0.6
        L3 = 0.6
        L4 = 0.6
        L5 = 0.6

        T01 =  np.array([
        [1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, np.cos(np.radians(theta1)), -np.sin(np.radians(theta1)), 0],
        [0, np.sin(np.radians(theta1)), np.cos(np.radians(theta1)), L1],
        [0, 0, 0, 1]
        ])

        T12 =  np.array([
        [1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, np.cos(np.radians(theta2)), -np.sin(np.radians(theta2)), 0],
        [0, np.sin(np.radians(theta2)), np.cos(np.radians(theta2)), L2],
        [0, 0, 0, 1]
        ])

        T23 =  np.array([
        [1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, d3+L3],
        [0, 0, 0, 1]
        ])


        T34 =  np.array([
        [1, 0, 0, -L4],
        [0, np.cos(np.radians(theta4)), -np.sin(np.radians(theta4)), 0],
        [0, np.sin(np.radians(theta4)), np.cos(np.radians(theta4)), 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1]
        ])

        T4ee =  np.array([
        [np.cos(np.radians(theta5)), 0, np.sin(np.radians(theta5)), 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0],
        [-np.sin(np.radians(theta5)), 0, np.cos(np.radians(theta5)), -L5],
        [0, 0, 0, 1]
        ])

        return T01, T12, T23, T34, T4ee


    def compute_direct_differential_kinematics_from_configuration(self, q, theta5):
        theta1, theta2, d3, theta4 = q

        T01, T12, T23, T34, T4ee = self.compute_transform_matrix(q)

        T02 = np.dot(T01, T12)
        T03 = np.dot(T02, T23)
        T04 = np.dot(T03, T34)
        T0ee = np.dot(T04, T4ee)

        P01 = T01[:3, 3]
        P02 = T02[:3, 3]
        P03 = T03[:3, 3]
        P04 = T04[:3, 3]
        P0ee = T0ee[:3, 3]
     
        P01 = P01.reshape(-1,1)
        P02 = P02.reshape(-1,1)
        P03 = P03.reshape(-1,1)
        P04 = P04.reshape(-1,1)
        P0ee = P0ee.reshape(-1,1)

        '''
        Z1 = base_joint (revolute)
        Z2 = base_spherical_joint (revolute)
        Z4 = arm_joint (revolute)
        Z5 = end_effector_joint (revolute)
        Z3 = leg_joint (prismatic)
        d3 = displacement across links of Z3
        Z3 = holding tool_mic link containing the microphone
        '''
        
        Z1 = np.dot(T01[:3,:3],np.array([[1], [0], [0]]))
        Z2 = np.dot(T02[:3,:3],np.array([[1], [0], [0]]))
        Z4 = np.dot(T03[:3,:3],np.array([[1], [0], [0]]))
        Z3 = np.dot(T04[:3,:3],np.array([[0], [0], [d3]]))
        Z5 = np.dot(T0ee[:3,:3],np.array([[0], [1], [0]]))

        J1 = np.vstack((np.cross(Z1, (P0ee - P01), axis=0), Z1))
        J2 = np.vstack((np.cross(Z2, (P0ee - P02), axis=0), Z2))
        J3 = np.vstack((np.array(Z3), np.array([[0],[0],[0]])))
        J4 = np.vstack((np.cross(Z4, (P0ee - P03), axis=0), Z4))
        J5 = np.vstack((np.cross(Z5, (P0ee - P04), axis=0), Z5))

        J = np.hstack((J1, J2, J3, J4, J5))
       
        return J

    def compute_motion(self, p_desired, graph, Kp, Kd):
        # Given end effector position matrix 
        p_desired = np.array([1, 2, 1])
        M  = self.compute_inertia_matrix()
        
        G = 9.81


        # Desired tolerance for convergence
        tolerance = 3

        # Maximum number of iterations
        tau_list = []
        # Numerical inverse kinematics using the Jacobian inverse method

        for idx, q_current in enumerate(graph):

            p_current = self.compute_forward_kinematics_from_configuration(q_current)
            error = np.linalg.norm(np.array(p_desired) - np.array(p_current))

            # Check if the error is below the tolerance
            if np.linalg.norm(error) < tolerance:
                print("Converged!")
                q_desired = q_current               
                q_dot_desired = np.gradient(q_desired, 0.01)
                q_ddot_desired = np.gradient(q_dot_desired, 0.01)
                q_dot = np.gradient(q_current, 0.01)

                # Update joint positions using the computed velocities
                q_current = q_current.astype(float)
                q_current += q_dot * 0.01 
                C = self.compute_coriolis_matrix(M, q_current, q_dot)
                tau_list_s = []
                for i in range(4):
                    tau = np.dot(M[i], (q_ddot_desired + np.dot(Kd, (q_dot_desired - q_dot)) + np.dot(Kp, (q_desired - q_current)))) + np.dot(C, q_dot) + G
                    tau_list_s.append(tau)
                tau_list.append(tau_list_s)

            else:
                print("Invalid joint configuration!")
                continue
        # Compute Jacobian matrix
        #J = compute_jacobian(q_current)

        # Compute joint velocities using the Jacobian inverse
            

        return tau_list
 
    def apply_torque(self, joint_name, torque, position):
        msg = JointTrajectory()
        msg.joint_names = [joint_name]
        pos_msg = float(position)
        point = JointTrajectoryPoint()
        dt = 0.1
        point.positions = [position]  # Set the joint position if required
        
        position = sp.Symbol('position')
        dt = sp.Symbol('dt')
        v = sp.Symbol('v')
        v = sp.diff(position, dt)
        a = sp.diff(v, dt)
        point.velocities = [v]  # Set the joint velocity if required
        point.accelerations = [a]
        point.effort = [torque]
        msg.points = [point]
        self.joint_trajectory_publisher.publish(msg)

        effort = ApplyJointEffort.Request()
        effort.joint_name = joint_name
        effort.effort = float(torque)
        
        effort.start_time = Time(sec=0, nanosec=0)
        effort.duration = Duration(sec=0, nanosec=0) # Duration of 0.1 seconds
        future = self.joint_effort_srv_client.call_async(effort)

        # Wait for the result
        rclpy.spin_until_future_complete(self, future)

        joint_state_msg = JointState()
        joint_state_msg.header.stamp = self.get_clock().now().to_msg()
        joint_state_msg.name = [joint_name]  # Add your joint names
        joint_state_msg.position = [pos_msg]  # Add your joint positions

        # Publish joint state information
        self.joint_state_publisher.publish(joint_state_msg)
        # Check if the request was successful
        if future.result() is not None:
            self.get_logger().info("Effort applied successfully")
        else:
            self.get_logger().error("Failed to apply effort")
        

    def control_script(self, joints, tau, graph, Kp, Kd):
       # Specify joint name (replace 'joint1' with your joint name)
        #for i in range(4):
        time_differential = 0.01
        dt = sp.Symbol('time_differential')
        for k, node in enumerate(graph):
            node = self.minimize_distance(node)
            for i, pos in enumerate(node):
                errors = graph[len(graph)-1][i] - pos
                position = sp.Symbol('pos')
                v = sp.diff(position, dt)
                # Compute the PD control signal
                pd_signal = Kp * errors + Kd * v

                # Add the PD control signal to the torques
                tau_modified = tau[k, i] + pd_signal

                if i<=3:
                    self.apply_torque(joints[i], tau_modified, pos)
                else:
                    joint_state_msg = JointState()
                    joint_state_msg.header.stamp = self.get_clock().now().to_msg()
                    joint_state_msg.name = [joints[i]]  # Add your joint names
                    joint_state_msg.position = [np.radians(30)]  # Add your joint positions

                    # Publish joint state information
                    self.joint_state_publisher.publish(joint_state_msg)


    def is_singular(self, J):
        okay = False
        num_dofs = 5  # Example: 3 degrees of freedom in task space
        if np.linalg.cond(J)>1e6:
            print('Singularity alert!')
            print('one')
        if np.linalg.matrix_rank(J)<num_dofs:
            print('Singularity alert!')
            print('two')
        elif np.linalg.eigvals(J) <=0.5:
            print('Singularity alert')
            print('three')
        else:
            print('no singularity! everything is fine :)!')
            okay = True

        # Perform singular value decomposition (SVD) on the Jacobian matrix
        if not okay:
            U, s, V = np.linalg.svd(J)

            # Find linearly dependent columns (where singular values are close to zero)
            linearly_dependent_indices = np.where(s < 1e-10)[0]


            print('Problematics columns:')
            for col_index in linearly_dependent_indices:                
                print(np.linalg.matrix_rank(J[:, col_index]))
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def solve_numerical_inverse_kinematics(self, q_initial, target_position, theta5):
        q_result = q_initial.copy()
        J = self.compute_direct_differential_kinematics_from_configuration(q_initial, theta5)

        for iteration in range(100):
        
            error = (target_position - self.compute_forward_kinematics_from_configuration(q_initial)).reshape(-1, 1)
            error = np.vstack((error, np.zeros_like(error)))
            delta_theta = 0.1 * np.linalg.pinv(J) @ error
            q_result = q_result.astype(float)
            delta_theta = ((delta_theta[:4]).flatten()).T
            q_result += delta_theta
            q_initial = q_result
            
            if np.linalg.norm(delta_theta) < 1e-6:
                if self.is_joint_okay(q_result):
                    break
                else:
                    continue
                        
                                
        return q_result.astype(int)
    

    def is_joint_okay(self, q_result):
        for i, joint in enumerate(self.robot_desc.joints):
            if q_result[i]>=joint.limit.lower and q_result[i]<=joint.limit.upper:
                print('Joint conf okay')
                if i==3:
                    break
            else:
                return False
        return True



    def minimize_distance(self, q_goal, theta5=np.radians(30)):
        null_step = 0.01
        q_goal_minimized = q_goal - (theta5 * null_step)
        if self.is_joint_okay(q_goal_minimized):
            return q_goal_minimized
        else: 
            return q_goal
       


def main(args=None):
    rclpy.init(args=args)
    node = RobotController()
    Kp = 0.5
    Kd = 0.1
    theta5 = 30
    try:
        while rclpy.ok():
            q_goal = node.solve_numerical_inverse_kinematics(np.array([0, 0, 0, 0]), np.array([1,2,1]), theta5)
            q_goal = node.minimize_distance(q_goal, theta5)
            graph = node.get_trajectory(q_goal, np.array([0, 0, 0, 0]))
            print(graph)
            tau = node.compute_motion(np.array([1,2,1]), graph, Kp, Kd)
            tau_arr = np.array(np.mean(tau, axis=2))
            print(tau_arr)
            joints = np.array(['base_joint', 'base_spherical_joint', 'leg_joint', 'arm_joint', 'end_effector_joint'])
            node.control_script(joints, tau_arr, graph, Kp, Kd)
            
            rclpy.spin(node)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    finally:
        node.destroy_node()
        rclpy.shutdown()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As you can see I am trying to move the robot from its initial configuration to target position. What am I doing wrong? The robot doesn't move on gazebo although efforts get applied. And another problem is, joint state messages don't show on console other messages like effort applied, can be seen. I am completely new on robotics so any help will be appreciated.